# Print grid of chess board in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a chess board grid but it's only printing the A file, then just prints out 7 more blank lines.

Here's my code:

```
public class Board
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        int col = 0;
        String spot;

        int[][] grid = new int [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i <= grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(; col < grid.length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I can't figure it out. What do I change to print a full chess board grid?

Comment: You know how to read an array, right?  You have to access an element like this `grid[1][2]`.  You print it the same way.  I don't see any attempt to use `grid` in your print statement, and you need to supply the indexes inside square brackets [ ].

Comment: see my answer. I pointed the issue and posted the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with enhanced for loop:

```
for(int[] row : grid){
     for(int square : row){
        System.out.print(square + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset col variable. Otherwise it won't execute the second for loop because the condition get failed col < grid.length.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char rows = 'a';
    int col = 0;
    String spot;

    int[][] grid = new int [8][8];

    for(int i = 0; i <= grid.length; i++, rows++)
    {
        for(col=0; col < grid.length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `col` variable should be initialized properly.

For loop condition should be proper.

see the below code:

```
public class Board
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char rows = 'a';
        String spot;

        int[][] grid = new int [8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++, rows++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[i].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(rows + "" + (col + 1) + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

output of this code is

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 
g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8
```